# Django Database List is empty even after publishing. DjangoGirls Tutorial

Tags: python, django, post, blogs

I am working on [DjangoGirls Tutorial](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/) to create a blog. This is my first time with Django and more or less with Python too.

Hi I ran into a problem.

Whatever I do, my `Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=False)` command still shows an empty list. Below is the commands and outputs:

```
>>> post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
>>> post.publish()
>>> Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=False)
[]
>>> post = Post.objects.get(id=2)
>>> post.publish()
>>> Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=False)
[]
>>> first = Post.objects.get(id=1)
>>> first.publish()
>>> Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=False)
[]
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?
I have these many posts in my database:

```
>>> Post.objects.all()
[<Post: Sample Title>, <Post: Sample-1 Title>, <Post: Sample-2 Title>, <Post: Sample-3 Title>, <Post: Sample-4 Title>, <Post: Sample-5 Title>, <Post: Sample-6 Title>]
```

And I have these many authors in the database:

```
>>> User.objects.all()
[<User: ola>, <User: dola>, <User: bula>, <User: kela>, <User: lala>]
```

I can't understand what's wrong then. Of course, this problem did not affect the project. I am continuing with the rest of the tutorial and it's going fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. The command `Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=False)` means if there is any post where published_date is not null, and it returns empty list means all posts have null published_date.

**EDIT**

Restart your shell and see if you get any data with `Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=False)`

Comment: Thanks @ruddra. The error was when I used web page of my Django admin page, I didn't set the publish date and time properly. Thanks again.